# MS SQL Server how to instantly insert a 1 to 10 number column to table (virtual column)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query, cross-join

any idea about to instantly add a column for number (1 to 10) for each rows value on existing table?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` in concert with an ad-hoc tally table

**Example**

```
Select A.*
      ,B.Code
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Join ( Select Top 10 Code=row_number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1 ) B
```

Comment: For a small number using `values` is simpler than a row_number() over ... subquery.  eg `cross join ( values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10) ) B(Code)`.

Comment: Hi bro, thanks alot, its really helped, i just try it at home its can, but i worry that my workplace still using the old database, does the cross join can user or not. i will try it and update again. thanks a lot

Comment: @hermansusandy You shouldn't have an issue.  CROSS JOIN simply creates a 1 to many on every record.   Row_Number() goes back to 2008

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the rows with a recurisve query, then cross join that with your table.

```
with codes as (
    select 1 code
    union all select code + 1 from cte where code < 10
)
select t.*, c.code
from mytable t
cross join codes c
```

For a small number of rows, I would expect the recusive query to be faster than `top 10` against a large table.